# Function does not work in MainActivity, but works in TextRecognizerActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

I have a **recogniseText()** function which does text recognition using google ML Kit, placed in TextRecognizerActivity. Initially, I received an image from gallery in MainActivity.kt, and passed it with an intent to TextRecognizerActivity. Everything was working fine.

Then I deleted TextRecognizerActivity and placed the **recogniseText()** function in MainActivity itself. Now it always executes the *addOnFailureListener* block. The only thing that changed was the context that was passed to it. Before, the context was **this@TextRecognizerActivity**, and now the context is **this@MainActivity**.

```
public fun recognizeText(uri:Uri, context: Context): ArrayList<String>{
        var itemsPurchased = ArrayList<String>()

        val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)
        val image = InputImage.fromFilePath(context,uri);
        val result = recognizer.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { visionText ->
                itemsPurchased = receiptProcessor(BasicReceipt(),visionText)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->

            }
        return itemsPurchased
    }
```

I debugged it. the *image* variable is populated, the uri is also populated correctly. The variable *itemsPurchased* is returned as an empty ArrayList.

Comment: This function should return an empty list every time because your success or failure listener will only be fired some time in the future after this function returns. [Read this question and the answers for an explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks man. Figured it out with the help of the link you provided.